# Debian 9, Shutting down too fast, inferior to 1 second

Tags: linux

I am working on the new version of debian (9) but unfortunately, i can't shut the system down properly, which mean when the system go down i don't see the shutting down message on the console, it go down as if i unplugged the machine from the sector.
i don't know if this gonna help before it goes down i can read this [367.512 802] reboot : power down ??? 
for your information i updated and upgrade the system.

step
- on the console, as root, i use the command poweroff or shutdown -h now both commands give me the same unexpected results.

if i'm not clear just let me know.

you will save my day with your help.

Comment: "it go down as if i unplugged the machine from the sector", what's causing you to conclude this?

Comment: because i don't see the shuttingdown message. it is stopping like there is no electricity

Comment: Does your computer do a disk scan when it boots?  Because if it really is shutting down like you said, your drives would detect they were not unmounted properly, and would proceed to scan them.  Is that what you are experiencing?

Comment: it does not do a scan disk at boot. it is not that my problem. to my side it is on  shutdown process, normally at shutdown you got the output message that let you see that the different services are stopped gracefully but in my case i have  a black screen with a quick message reboot: power down  and then the computer go down (it takes less than 1 seconde)

Comment: Do you actually have any services on it that require a longer shutdown process?

Comment: here is the list of the package i have installed

Comment: the package i have installed are mariadb, php7, samba, rsync, apache2, subversion, i don't think so that it take more than a minute to stop

Comment: I resolved my problem by adding this line to the kernel options: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet systemd.show_status=1" , now i can see the startup messages and shutdown messages. thanks to everyone who tried to help me. best regards Diogène